# How to Set up an Email When a Windows Service Fails

Tags: windows, services

We currently have a service that is failing and need to be notified when it does. How to set up the service to send an email when it fails.

Comment: Is it a third party service or something you are developing? If it is a common service, what's its name/purpose?

Comment: Is a [commercial solution](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceProtector/) OK?

Answer (score 7):

It is easy to get a Windows Service to run a program when it fails. 
Go to the `Services` snap-in, find the service, double click, and go to the `Recovery` tab. There you can choose what happens when it fails.

One of the options is `Run a Program`. You can write a script or program that sends an email, and simply point this at it. An easy way is to use Windows' `wscript`.  See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152323/send-mail-from-a-windows-script).

[image: Service Control Dialog]