# How to get Deluge to run as a service and show in tray?

Tags: windows, deluge

New to Deluge; I'm trying to get Deluge to run either as a Windows service or a Windows Task (to make sure it stays running at all times) while **also** running in the Tray.

Deluge is weird ... if I double-click either it's shortcut or deluge.exe, it'll load the GUI and minimize to the tray (I set that setting), but if you add deluge.exe or deluge-gtk.exe as either a service or task, when it runs it'll just show deluge/gtk.exe running in the process list, but not in the tray.

I want it this way because I want access to the webUI while also having the GUI running in tray, while also having some sort of check to make sure it's running all the time. It's a server machine, so most of the time I'll be remoting into the webui, but at times I'll also be in front of the machine and want to use the regular GUI.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Windows services cannot have interactive access to the desktop since Windows Vista,
so this is not the direction to go.

If you would like the program to always run when you are logged-in
(without login there is no taskbar icon),
copy the link to it into the Startup menu group.

The All Users startup folder, for start up programs for all users,
is located at:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

Comment: Thanks, but adding it to the startup folder(s)/registry key(s) doesn't make sure that it's always running (i.e. if it were to crash). Adding as a service/task adds the ability to auto-restart it if it crashes.

Comment: Without login there is no taskbar and no icon, so your requirement cannot be met.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true, but lets skip that part for now. ;) and focus on why double-clicking deluge.exe (or the gtk version) when already logged in loads it up with the full GUI, and starting it as a service only shows it in the process list (no GUI, even when already logged in)? You can test this by using `nssm` and creating a service for deluge.exe, then starting the service.

Comment: I already answered that - for security reasons a service is not allowed to interact with the desktop.

Comment: What's this for? https://i.imgur.com/usGEOv3.png

Comment: That doesn't help, it remains from XP and will show output on a virtual desktop too primitive to be useful. It's mostly meant for debug.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I would definitely advise against trying to run the Deluge GUI as service as there are known issues with Gtk memory crashes over extended periods of time. If you want to run Deluge as service then you should use the Deluge daemon as detailed in the [Deluge ThinClient guide](https://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient)

There is no way to have a status icon for the `deluged` service and from what I have read, it is discouraged for a service to have a UI. However I feel that what you actually want is to be notified if the service fails or stops, e.g. email, popup, etc. So perhaps try this other [SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/588096/72950)